# how to get when user created or last modified in asp net core and entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core

It is simple, I want to know how to get when user created or last modified in asp net core and entity framework?

because I didnt find column of `createdAt` and `LastModifiedAt` in `AspNetUsers` table in database generated by dotnet core.

I also search in other generated table, but still same.

so how to get when user created or last modified in asp net core and entity framework?

Comment: Have you tried extending the IdentityUser and the UserStore / UserManager?

Comment: nope, because still searching in database, I making ERD of asp net user now

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a little work to get those information of a user by using profile parameters in your webconfig file. Check 
[this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx) to read more.

```
<profile>
  <properties>
    <add name="LastModifiedAt" type="System.DateTime"/>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

When a user modifies his or her account. Add the below code to the OnClicked event

```
Profile.LastModifiedAt = DateTime.Now;
```